# How to expand frames dynamically in JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

```
frame
  text field: short | text field: very long text causing linebreak
frame
  other elements
```

How do I have to configure jasper reports so that the long text field moves all subsequent frames and elements down? (ie: causes a resize of the frames dynamically)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: make the text fields `float; stretch relative to tallest object; overflow` and make the surrounding frames `float; no stretch`.

This is very counter-intuitive that an expanding frame will have to be set to `no stretch` in order to expand, and move any subsequent elements down accordingly.

Comment: What if the frames are side by side?

Comment: stretch relative to tallest object is deprecated in newer versions